# How to resize Bootstrap 3.2.0 carousel image size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap v3.2.0. 
Currently i am facing a problem with the carousel images. I have high pixels images. and i want to show those images perfectly within specific height. 
I put these on my css file.

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

but problem is, the width is perfect with 100%, but the the images height is not adjust along with the height of the carousel.

What should i do ?

Thank You

Comment: What is the specific selector the image? It's all very well setting the max height and width as 100%, but that's the max and not the actual value. Also setting the width on .caoursel-inner from my understanding could also not affect anything. 

Could you post all the divs and possibly the specific selector for the images :)

Comment: please check the html file from the following link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7HcXQ95u5GMS3FnSFRKaW4wN1E/view

Comment: Please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Try using in your CSS - item img { width:100%; height:100%; } You shouldn't need to go any deeper than that to alter the images, but if you do, just trace the path using F12